# ¿Por qué se usa el artículo "el" en "el jefe de la banda es el carismático Butch Cassidy"?

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, artículos

¿Por qué se usa el artículo "el" en "el jefe de la banda es el carismático Butch Cassidy"? ¿Se refiere "el" en este caso a "carismático" o a "Butch Cassidy"? ¿Se puede decir también en este caso "el (muy) carismático de Butch Cassidy"?

Aquí está la [oración original](https://www.filmaffinity.com/cl/reviews/13/376708.html?orderby=5):

> Un grupo de jóvenes pistoleros se dedica a asaltar los bancos del estado de Wyoming y el correo ferroviario de la Unión Pacific. El jefe de la banda es **el carismático Butch Cassidy**, y su principal e inseparable compañero es Sundance Kid, otra de las pistolas más rápidas del Oeste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En este caso **carismático** se esta utilizando como adjetivo de "**Butch Cassidy**", así que el artículo es para indicar al sujeto entero "**el carismático Butch Cassidy**".

Nótese que solamente sucede cuando se adjetiviza al sujeto.

En caso contrario la oracion es completamente funcional sin el "el" si se omite el adjetivo:

> El jefe de la banda es Butch Cassidy.

Así que tenemos los siguientes casos:

> **El jefe de la banda es carismático Butch Cassidy** -- Este caso solo será correcto si "carismático" es parte del nombre
>
> **El jefe de la banda es el Butch Cassidy** -- Solo será correcto si "Butch" es titulo o adjetivo.
>
> **El jefe de la banda es Butch Cassidy** -- Es correcto.
>
> **El jefe de la banda es el carismático Butch Cassidy** -- Es correcto.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones!

Answer (score 9):

*Carismático* es un adjetivo. El artículo *el* se aplica a toda la frase nominal, *carismático Butch Cassidy*.

Esta forma de calificar a una persona (o a un lugar o una cosa) es muy particular porque 1) se debe usar el artículo definido, y 2) el adjetivo va antes del sustantivo, en vez de después, como es lo más común en castellano. Cuando un adjetivo se usa de esta manera se dice que es un **[epíteto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ep%C3%ADteto)**. Dice Wikipedia:

> **Epíteto** es el adjetivo calificativo que resalta las
>   características y cualidades de un sustantivo (el frío en la nieve, el
>   calor en el fuego, la humedad en el agua, entre otros), sin
>   distinguirlo de los demás de su grupo. Son muy frecuentes acompañando
>   nombres de divinidades, reyes o personajes históricos.

Al referirse a alguien como *el carismático Butch Cassidy* queremos decir que Butch Cassidy es carismático y que eso es algo bien sabido y parte inseparable de su personalidad, de la misma manera que sabemos que el sol es caliente. Otros ejemplos (con nombres propios y comunes de lugares y personas):

- *la verde hierba*
- *la ancha pradera*
- *el populoso Oriente*
- *el poderoso Amazonas*
- *la malvada Reina de Corazones*
- *los codiciosos Enanos*

Aunque no siempre es así necesariamente, el significado suele cambiar si se pone el adjetivo detrás del sustantivo. Si decimos *el Butch Cassidy carismático*, suena como si hubiese varios Butch Cassidy (¿Cassidies?) y sólo uno fuese carismático.

Se puede añadir *muy* (u otro adverbio o frase adverbial) antes de *carismático* (se pueden decir cosas como *el ya no tan terriblemente carismático Butch Cassidy*), pero no se debe añadir la preposición *de* en este caso. Esa estructura (artículo definido + adjetivo + *de* + sustantivo/nombre propio) significa otra cosa y se usa casi siempre con adjetivos peyorativos (de connotación negativa), por ejemplo: *el tonto de Butch Cassidy*.